# String to int in c++

Tags: string, int

How to convert a string variable that consists of maximum 100 char to big int ?

My code:

```
 long long int x;
 string s="11111111111111111111111111111111";
 x=atoll(s.c_str());
 cout<<x;
```

Comment: What is the maximum value that can be stored in such a "long long int" value? How many characters does the maximum value that can be represented have (in the desired base encoding)? That will be a limiting factor for any standard integer type.. and it's well below "100 char".

Comment: Hint: log10(2 ^ 128) is approximately 38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a bignum library, like **GNU MP aka GMP** or **libcrypto**.

Since in a 64-bit environment most compiler use 64 bits for a `long long int`, you can't even reach *near* 100 decimal digits with a `long long`.